# Why does Crashlytics go into an infinite loop for an unhandled exception?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have just updated to the latest Crashlytics. I tried testing it by throwing an unhandled exception.

It did not send a bug report.
The app simply froze.
Checking the debugger, it appears to be in an infinite loop.
If I pause threads in the debugger, it looks like the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SOFI.png)

That is absolutely unacceptable. I can't ship an app like this.

This is in build.gradle at the app level.

```
 // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.1'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
```

This in build.gradle at the project level:

```
    // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin.
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
```

Comment: Firebaser here - as far as I can tell we haven't received any infinite loop issues recently, so this is definitely strange. Could you add more info to the OP about how exactly you're triggering this crash, as well as trying to reproduce this behavior with debug mode enabled? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?platform=android#enable_debug_logging. If you're comfortable attaching the log output with debug mode, it could give more insight.